# How to display Name in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

Please help me, I want to display the name of the users from the table according to `sender_id` and `recipient_id`, how do the code model and view in my CodeIgniter

[Tables schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCqkm.png)

[Data Table users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYNta.jpg)

[Data Table Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Np4yS.jpg)

Model

```
function get_pesan_view(){
    $this->db->from('messages');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = messages.sender_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = messages.recipient_id', 'left');
    $q2 = $this->db->get();
    return $q2->result();
 }
```

Contoller

```
public function view_pesan()
{
    $data['get_pesan']=$this->Emp_model->get_pesan_view();
    $this->load->view('employee/top');
    $this->load->view('employee/nav', $data);
    $this->load->view('employee/slidbar', $data);
    $this->load->view('employee/pesan', $data);
    $this->load->view('employee/bottom');
}
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($get_pesan as $pesan) { ?>
<strong> Sender : <?php echo $pesan->name ; ?> </strong>
<strong> Recipient : <?php echo $pesan->name ; ?> </strong>
<a> <?php echo $pesan->body ; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to display the name of the sender and recipient together in view

Comment: Sender and Recipient name are different or same?

Comment: Don't pass `$data` to nav and sidebar

Comment: Add DB structure in question

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
public function get_names(){

  $this->load->model('model_name'); //If not loaded in the autoload.php file
  $names = $this->model_name->all_names();
  $this->load->view('view_file_name', compact('names'));
}
```

The query in the model will be like this

```
public function all_names(){
  $this->db->select('name');
  $this->db->from('users');
  $this->db->join('messages', 'users.id = messages.sender_id');
  return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

To join with `recipient_id` do like this

```
$this->db->join('messages', 'users.id = messages.recipient_id');
```

Then use `foreach` loop to show all `names` in the view

```
foreach($names as $row){
   echo $row->name;
}
```

Comment: I have tried the code, what if I want to call the name in accordance with recipiant_id?

Comment: what if I call sender_id and recipient_id becomes the name display in the view together

Comment: <a> sender <? php echo ＄ data-> name; ?> </a> <a> recipient <? php echo ＄ data-> name; ?> </a> doesn't work

Comment: @Laces add complete code that you have tried so far in your question

Comment: New query will build to call name with `sender_id` and `recipient_id`

Comment: sender and recipiant appears with the same name in the view, even though the value is different ... example sender_id = 1 (name: ahmad), recipient_id = 2 (name: jhon)

Answer (score 0):

model

```
    $this->db->select('messages.*,u1.{name of field for username} as sender_name,u2.{name of field for username} as recipient_name');
   $this->db->from('messages');
    $this->db->join('users u1', ' u1.id = messages.sender_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('users u2', ' u2.id = messages.recipient_id', 'left');
    $q2 = $this->db->get();
    return $q2->result();
```

View

```
<?php foreach ($get_pesan as $pesan) { ?>
<strong> Sender : <?php echo $pesan->sender_name; ?> </strong>
<strong> Recipient : <?php echo $pesan->recipient_name; ?> </strong>
<a> <?php echo $pesan->body ; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

i have forgotten you cannot join one tale more than one time you need to use table aliases. it will work for you/ just place the name what ever fild name is in your data base. 
it will work or else share me screen short of your table and error pages

Comment: error Number 1066, Not unique table/alias : ‘users’